# Assign the value of the field to Form Parent

Tags: delphi

In my application, I save the component names in a database for use in the future.
In the following example, I want to assign the value of the field from Table1 to the Form1.Parent:

```
Form1.Parent: = DM.Table1.FieldByName('NOM_PANEL').AsString;
```

I get the following message:

```
[dcc32 Error] UPrincipale.pas (794): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TWinControl' and 'string'
```

I have to convert String to TWinControl.
How please resolve this problem ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search for a component by its name, use its Owner's `FindComponent()` method, or its Parent's `FindChildControl()` method.

For example, let's say you want to assign `Form2.Panel1` to `Form1.Parent`, and `Panel1` is *owned* by `Form2`, and `AsString` returns just `'Panel1'`, then you would use:

```pascal
Form1.Parent := Form2.FindComponent(DM.Table1.FieldByName('NOM_PANEL').AsString) as TWinControl;
```

Comment: Thank you Remy.  My Form1 is displayed in a Panel1. What code I have to write please to affect:
 `Form1.Parent: = DM.Table1.FieldByName ('NOM_PANEL'). AsString;` . have you an example please?